# Flutter: Localization from API call

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization, intl

I wish to localize a Flutter application where locales are fetched by an API call, given the requested language.

I was hoping to be able to use the `Intl` package or something similar, but I am not sure this is possible without the .arb files.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this without reinventing the wheel?

(Having the localizations stored locally is not an option)

Comment: You can create your own class implementation for INTL, In that class define all the necessary English variables and store it there. And lets say you want switch to spanish, you can call your api, load all the english variables to there spanish conterpart and hence you will be able to deal with localization

Comment: @DishankJindal I'm not sure I quite follow, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) has the functionality described. Simply creating a custom HttpAssetLoader and passing it to the easy_localization initialization method works out of the box, and provides device language detection, and application rebuild on locale change as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Down below, you can see a class which is converted to a singleton pattern. You can use any service locator package. It will be the same thing.

Now you can call this class in your main function, default set to EN.

[image]

Now let's say, you want to support SPANISH and not want to use .arb files

Now you can call google translate and replace values with the existing one. for every variable. I hope this helps.

Comment: This could work, ideally I would want to integrate with existing packages that already handles the system locale and so on like Intl or easy_localization. But perhaps I have to do it from scratch and use something like this

Answer (score 1):

Use https://pub.dev/packages/localizely_sdk package, it provides what you want to achieve